# Writing with a PrintWriter to a file doesn't come out right

Tags: java, output, printwriter

```
public static void doubleSpace(String fileName) {
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);
        String outputFileName = fileName.charAt(0) + ".ds";
        PrintWriter pOut = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
        // Opening of files for input and output
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            pOut.println(line + "\n");
            pOut.print("\n");
            // System.out.println(line + "\n"); //Test
        }
        pOut.close(); // Close the files if they have been opened.

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

So basically my input file contains

```
a
b
c
```

and my output file should look like

```
a

b

c
```

However, my output file always contains only `abc`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your program runs fine on my computer. Check if any exception is raised

Comment: So, you are trying to double the newlines?

Comment: Are you using notepad to open file in windows? "\n" is only a newline character , but for notepad, the you only see line wrapped while the line end with "\r\n". Try some other text editor to open the file.

Comment: Single `pOut.println(line + "\n");` should be enough, as `println` terminates the string with a newline plus the `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `BufferedWriter`. It has a `.newLine()` method. This method will use the platform's default line separator.

And use a `BufferedReader`. It has a `.readLine()` method.

Example:

```
// NOTE: you should really be using UTF-8
final Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();

final Path src = Paths.get(filename);
final Path dst = Paths.get(filename + ".ds");

String line;

try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(src, charset);
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dst, charset);
) {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.write(line);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.newLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely useing the wrong character(s) for new line for your plattform. Use

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

to get the right value.